# Conditional picture in an access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to know whether it is possible or not to display a conditional picture in a form. Example:

if X>0 then picture 1 is displayed else picture 2 is displayed

I have looked for it but I didn't find anything

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If X > 0 Then
    Me.Picture = "c:\picture1.jpg"
Else
    Me.Picture = "c:\picture2.jpg"
End If
```

Or if the picture is not directly on the form, but in a image control:

```
If X > 0 Then
    Me.NameOfImageControl.Picture = "c:\picture1.jpg"
Else
    Me.NameOfImageControl.Picture = "c:\picture2.jpg"
End If
```

---

**EDIT:**

Okay, you can do this when you have the form open in design mode:

- there is a button in the toolbar to open the code window:
  [image: code window button]
  *(the screenshot is from Access 2003, I don't know which version you're using)*
- you can run code on events in the form like when the form is opened or closed.
  Check out [this tutorial](http://proicereinc.com/Documents/MS%20Access%20%28Macros%20and%20Modules%29.pdf) (Page 10).

And here is another tutorial about [VBA Basics in Access](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/vbabasics/basics01.php).

Comment: But how can I do it if I don't use any programming tool ?

Comment: You **do** use a programming tool...MS Access is one :-)

Comment: @Holden: or is your problem that you don't know where to put my code?

Comment: yeah that's it. I'm a beginner with Access, I can use all the classical tools, but how can I put programming into my form ? (I have good knowledge in .NET)